# Unable to populate dropdown using Extension Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, controller-extension

Here is my code, please help me what am I doing wrong

VisualForce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" recordSetVar="Contacts" extensions="myContactExtension">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:selectList size="1" multiselect="false"  >
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!getOptions}" />
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Extension Controller:

```
public class myContactExtension {

    List<Contact> contacts;
    public myContactExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        contacts = (List<Contact>) controller.getSelected();
    }

    public List<ApexPages.SelectOption> getOptions() {
        List<ApexPages.SelectOption> options = new List<ApexPages.SelectOption>();
        options.add(new ApexPages.SelectOption('','--SELECT--'));

        for(Account_Plan__c p:[select name from account_plan__c order by name asc]) {
            options.add(new ApexPages.SelectOption(p.id, p.name));
        }
        return options;
    }

}
```

Error:

> Error: Unknown property 'ContactStandardController.getOptions'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `<apex:selectOptions value="{!Options}"/>`   when you use the 'get'  apex thinks you are exposing a getter / setter method..

Hence this example.. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_selectoption.htm